# Is there a reasonable Grothendieck topology on the category of modules over a ring?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

How about over a field (i.e. f.d vector spaces)? Can these categories be considered as a site?

Comment: Much as in point set topology, we have minimal and maximal Grothendieck topologies. So it all depends on what you mean by "reasonable".

Comment: I am not sure what these notions mean in categorical language...I guess there must be size issues and questions like that. I was just wondering if there is an explicit function J that associates a collection of sieves on every f.d. vector space such that the Grothendieck axioms are satisfied. You say there are many coverages...How many?

Comment: There are at least two: one where only maximal sieves are covering, and another where every sieve is covering.

Comment: No, I definitely don't like the first. But I think I don't like the second either...So nothing exciting.

Comment: There are more describable choices than just these extrema. Perhaps the most natural topology is the regular topology, which in this case just has coverings generated by epimorphisms. Still not exciting, of course.

Comment: Incidentally, in the case of vector spaces over a field, the regular topology coincides with the topology in which only the maximal sieves cover.